# Understanding surface tension mathematically

Tags: material-science, surface-tension, liquid-state

According to my textbook surface tension is the force which acts perpendicular to a surface and is given  by,

$$F=\int \vec{S}\cdot \vec{dl}$$

As in the surface tension per length * perimeter of object

I wish to ask what is the connection between this formula and the molecular intrepetation of surface tension. That is nature of molecules to pull itself inwards? Also I see that we technically integrating over a boundary so does that suggest this is some residue of stokes theoreM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many molecules have a certain degree of *polarity*. Therefore, those that are surrounded by similar molecules in a homogeneous fluid tend to have a vanishing net force acting on them. Those that are close or on the surface won't be completely surrounded by similar molecules and will experience a net electrostatic force pulling them inward. These forces are such that the fluid tends to settle into a shape that minimises its surface.

You can then expect that any attempt of changing this shape will result in a resistance from the fluid, which naturally tends to move back to its "optimal" shape. Because the elasticity of liquids is quite low, we can assume that the volume is a fixed quantity. With this constraint, one cannot stretch a mass of liquid arbitrarily in two independent directions. Therefore, any stretching of a liquid must occur along a one dimensional manifold, i.e. a curve.

Suppose then that we have a volume of liquid enclosed by the surface $S\subset\mathbb R^3$. Pick a curve $\gamma:\mathbb R\to S$ on $S$ and describe the stretching of this volume of liquid along $\gamma$ via a displacement field $\delta:\text{Im}(\gamma)\to\mathbb R^3$. If $\hat{\mathbf n}(x)$ is the normal to the surface $S$ at the point $x\in S$, and $\mathbf f(x)$ is the linear density of the force on a point $x$ of $\gamma$, then we have, by definition of surface tension as the ratio between the work necessary to increase the area, per unit of area,

$$\tau_s = \frac{\delta W}{\delta A}=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac{\displaystyle\int_\gamma\mathbf f(\gamma(l))\cdot\delta(\gamma(l))\Vert\dot\gamma(l)\Vert\text dl}{2\displaystyle\int_\gamma\hat{\mathbf n}(\gamma(l))\cdot[\dot\gamma(l)\times\delta(\gamma(l))]\text dl}.$$

For example, if you were stretching a disk of initial radius $r$, you would get

$$\tau_s = \lim_{\delta\to0}\frac{\frac F{2\pi r}\cdot \delta\cdot 2\pi r}{2\cdot\delta\cdot2\pi r} = \frac F{4\pi r}.$$

However, I believe that a better description of surface tension comes from the notion of surface stress, which allows you to give, perhaps, a cleaner description of what is going on. In this case, the assumption is that the variation of (free) energy $\delta W$ is proportional to the *strain* tensor $\epsilon$. You are then after the force density $f$ (which is also a tensor) that gives you

$$\delta W = \sum_{i,j=1}^3f_{ij}\epsilon_{ij}$$

Comment: What is $\delta$? and where did u get $ \frac{F}{2\pi r}$

Comment: $\delta$ is a displacement field and $f = \frac{F}{2\pi r}$ comes from the symmetry of the disk.